# Spring Boot add my own endpoint as endpoint management

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

i'm pretty new to spring framework and all the spring-* i started to dive into spring boot and evaluate it as candidate for a new product build around REST services.

At the moment i'm interested in what is exposed via the "**actuator**" module, out of the box i know that i can gather info (/info) monitoring hook (/health) and even a shutdown endpoint, all decoupled from the main server by providing a configuration option to put thoses endpoints under a specific port and 'namespace'

```
management.port=9000
management.contextPath=/admin
```

I'm looking for a hint to add my own endpoint to those already defined (NB i don't want to enrich existing endpoint like what is proposed with HealthIndicator, but i really want to add a new one like say '/admin/get_me_out_of_load_balancers')

I can see that all the existing endpoints extends AbstractEndpoint but didn't manage to get my endpoint available under the management contextPath...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Expose an instance of your `Endpoint` class as a bean; Spring Boot's actuator auto-configuration [will discover it](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/55650bd61887cbfddabbb5167acbf9121682d7fe/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/mvc/MvcEndpoints.java#L62-L66) automatically. For example:

```
package demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.Endpoint;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public static Endpoint exampleEndpoint() {
        return new Endpoint<String>() {
            @Override
            public String getId() {
                return "example";
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isEnabled() {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isSensitive() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public String invoke() {
                return "example";
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Just saying, you can call it by `curl 127.0.0.1:<port>/example`

Answer (score 1):

For Spring Boot 2 have a look at sample: 
[Spring Boot Actuator: 5.2. Custom Endpoint](https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-actuator/)

```
@Component
@Endpoint(id = "custom-endpoint")
public class CustomEndpoint{

  @ReadOperation
  public String custom() {
    return "custom-end-point";
  }

  @ReadOperation
  public String customEndPointByName(@Selector String name) {
    return "custom-end-point";
  }

  @WriteOperation
  public void writeOperation(@Selector String name) {
    //perform write operation
  }

  @DeleteOperation
  public void deleteOperation(@Selector String name){
    //delete operation
  }
}
```

Also see [Introducing Actuator Endpoints in Spring Boot 2.0](https://dzone.com/articles/introducing-actuator-endpoints-in-spring-boot-20)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily implement it in a separate class with `AbstractMvcEndpoint` and use `@RequestMapping` to simplify or add params to the endpoint, so you can look up other services information:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.AbstractMvcEndpoint;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.ServiceInstance;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.SpringClientFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;
import com.netflix.loadbalancer.DynamicServerListLoadBalancer;
import com.netflix.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerStats;
import com.netflix.loadbalancer.Server;
import lombok.Builder;

@Configuration
public class BalancingEndpoint extends AbstractMvcEndpoint {

    @Value("${spring.application.name}")
    private String localServiceName;

    @Autowired
    private SpringClientFactory springClientFactory;

    @Autowired
    private DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;

    public BalancingEndpoint() {
        super("/balancing", false);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public BalancingResponse get() {
        return getEndpointContent(localServiceName);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{serviceName}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public BalancingResponse get(@PathVariable("serviceName") String serviceName) {
        return getEndpointContent(serviceName);
    }

    private BalancingResponse getEndpointContent(String serviceName) {

        DynamicServerListLoadBalancer loadBalancer = (DynamicServerListLoadBalancer) springClientFactory.getLoadBalancer(serviceName);

        return BalancingResponse.builder()
            .discovery(discoveryClient.getLocalServiceInstance())
            .loadBalancerStats(loadBalancer.getLoadBalancerStats())
            .loadBalancerAllServers(loadBalancer.getAllServers())
            .build();
    }

    @Builder
    @JsonPropertyOrder({"discovery", "loadBalancerStats", "loadBalancerAllServers"})
    public static class BalancingResponse {

        @JsonProperty
        ServiceInstance discovery;

        @JsonProperty
        private LoadBalancerStats loadBalancerStats;

        @JsonProperty
        private List<Server> loadBalancerAllServers;
    }
}
```

Also, it's interesting to consider this ([+info](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-customizing-endpoints-programmatically)):

> If you are doing this as a library feature consider adding a
>   configuration class annotated with @ManagementContextConfiguration to
>   /META-INF/spring.factories under the key
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementContextConfiguration.
>   If you do that then the endpoint will move to a child context with all
>   the other MVC endpoints if your users ask for a separate management
>   port or address. A configuration declared this way can be a
>   WebConfigurerAdapter if it wants to add static resources (for
>   instance) to the management endpoints.